# Date going 3 hour back in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, angular7

I'm using Angular 7. And I have a datepicker. And forexample, I'm choosing `2019-03-26`. But when I click `save` button, Then console show me as `2019-03-25T21:00:00.000Z` . **It going 3 hour back**. What can be the reason of this bug?

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zev9qb)

I'm using primeng 7.0.5.

Comment: I checked your `stackblitz` and opened the `console.log` and it is showing normally, by me it says `Mon Mar 18 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100`

Comment: Did you choose 18.03.2019 @Spritzig ?

Comment: Yes I choosed `13.08.2019`

Comment: You are looking browser console. But, I'm saying stackblitz console @Spritzig

Comment: you are right it is showing me a hour earlier

Comment: It shows current date and time for me (on givent stackblitz)

Comment: You are looking browser console. But, I'm saying stackblitz console @Antoniossss Not `GMT` time, with `T` time.

Comment: It depends on your machine local time zone

Comment: Yes. It depends on machine local time zone. But, when I post my object, I'm taking incorrect data from my service @DudanRadovanovic

Comment: Ye still shows valid time. All you have to do is to take into account that the time passed from UI is ZONED time. No problem there.

Comment: @HasanOzdemir time zone should not matter for you - just dont forget to use it on parsing side. T -> UTC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Primeng calendar has a property `dataType` . DataType is `date` in default. If you set `string` instead of `date`, then it's working perfectly and sending correct date to server.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qajvxy)

You can see from working example from this stackblitz link.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this is happening because you are seeing the console.log of Stackblitz server simulated browser window, So it's printing the DateTime in UTC timezone by server simulated console log.

```
{birthDate: "2019-03-15T14:56:04.000Z"} //Printin UTC Time
```

To check it the right way is to click on **Open in new Window** and then it will show the right DateTime like below.

[image]

[**Here is live window**](https://angular-zev9qb.stackblitz.io/)

Comment: This answer is not valid - and for whats worst - missleading. Calendar pics dates in current (browser/user) data zone. What you see in console is EXACT SAME POINT IN TIME but in UTC time zone. To sum up - both dates - in browser console and "stackblitz" console are VALID and shows exact same point in time.

Comment: But, in my real application, there are a lot of input in my form. And I'm sending my data directly by  `this.http.post(url, formData)` . And when I send my data to service, my data going 3 hour back @TheParam.

Comment: @HasanOzdemir it is your responsibility to keep time zone information with date and that is easily doable using ISO format.

Comment: I create new c# project and I create new angular project. And I didn't make any configuration. Everything is default. And my client and my server is the same. It's in my computer. I think, if I post item then it should send correct time @Antoniossss . I think that, it isn't my responsibility.

Comment: And again - time is sent correctly. `2019-03-26T00:00:00+03:00` is the same point in time as `2019-03-25T21:00:00.000Z`. Its like naming the same thing in different languages. The fact that you have "default" everything means nothing. Just send the date in ISO and maybe you will be fine "by default"

Answer (score 1):

You are in a local time zone, while the date picker gives back dates in UTC. You can correct it by reducing the timezone offset from the UTC date.

As the timezone offset comes in minutes, but Date objects calculate in milliseconds since 1970, you'll need to multiply the offset with 1000 * 60.

```
const utcDate = '2019-05-01T00:00:00Z';
const localDate = new Date(new Date(utcDate) - new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 1000 * 60);
```

Comment: But, in my real application, there are a lot of input in my form. And I'm sending my data directly by  `this.http.post(url, formData)` . So, it's very difficult to get date and parse @fjc

Comment: Why would you (except for display)? It's a good practice to store dates in UTC.

Comment: I'm sending my data to C# service @jjc. And it's sending as 3 hour back to my C# service.

Comment: No. You are just in a time zone +3 hours from UTC. If you store the date as UTC, you'll be fine. It still points to exactly the same point in time.

Comment: I'm not doing anything adiitonally @jjc. I'm only sending by 
 `this.http.post(url,this.myForm.value)` , and I'm taking from my C# service as 3 hour back. How can I solve this?

Comment: Either make your C# service properly handle UTC dates (probably the best option); or always send the date in your local time (as I show above).

Comment: I create new c# project and I create new angular project. And I didn't make any configuration. Everything is default. And my client and my server is the same. It's in my computer. But, my problem is continueing. **How can I make my C# service properly handle UTC dates ?** Because, I don't know how I can do that. @fjc

Answer (score 0):

Most of UI calendars store entered date as UTC (Coordinated Universal Time) date or timestamp. But displayed to user date is converted with your local timezone, which may be different from the UTC.

`console.log(_Date_)` prints UTC time, if you want to see this time in your local timezone you can use ate's methods like `getHours()`.

So, if you print `this.myForm.value.birthDate.getHours()` you will see your correct local hours. But you should not convert stored time to your local

Comment: But, in my real application, there are a lot of input in my form. And I'm sending my data directly by  `this.http.post(url, formData)` . So, it's very difficult to get date and parse @Andriy

Comment: your form (including `myForm.value.birthDate`) is absolutely correct, all the dates are stored / passed in UTC format. You could also convert it to timestamp, something like `myForm.value.birthDate.getTime()`. When you will display this date in another calendar in another timezone, it will show exactly the same time but according to the current timezone

Comment: My problem is, when I send my form by `this.http.post(url,this.myForm.value)`, then I getting my C# service as 3 hours back @Andriy

Comment: You need to use same formats on both server and client. I guess you can convert on server `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(YOUR_UTC_DATE)`. Or compare you client date with server UTC time (something like `DateTime.UtcNow`). Using UTC will help you to be synced in case client and server are in different time zones

Comment: I create new c# project and I create new angular project. And I didn't make any configuration. Everything is default. And my client and my server is the same. It's in my computer. But, it still continueing the same problem. @Andriy

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the timezone offset. 
What you get from the form is the date in GMT, So, when you try to print the date on console, you'll have the time adjusted to your local time zone. So you have to adjust the date time to local time zone when you print it.

Try this:

```
 save() {
    let localDate = new Date( this.myForm.value.birthDate.getTime() + Math.abs(this.myForm.value.birthDate.getTimezoneOffset()*60000) ) 
    console.log(this.myForm.value);
    console.log(localDate);
  }
```

Comment: But, in my real application, there are a lot of input in my form. And I'm sending my data directly by this.http.post(url, formData) . So, it's impossible to parse all dates. And also if developer forget writing this, then will create incorrect datas in my database. @Aragorn

Comment: Send the time API, not the input you get from form, use `this.myForm.value.birthDate.getTime()`

Comment: How can I achieve @ Aragorn? I'm writing only `this.http.post(url,this.myForm.value)` . I'm not doing additional thing.

Comment: And what does the API do with birthDate? save it to database? At some point in the flow, you'll have to get the birthDate from the form and save, and that is where you apply the timezone offset to it. Is the API JavaScript?